# I have reset my phone samsung galaxy fit through factory data reset... Now my contacts are deleted

Tags: factory-reset, data-recovery

How can I recover my contacts? (They were stored on phone memory.) I have also saved all my sd card data.

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't synced them with your Google Account, nor you stored them in your sim card, then your contacts are lost since a factory reset means a wipe of the phone memory.